# setState((){}); is not updating Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have a question about updating Android Emulator after pressing on an icon using setState()

this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dicee'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int leftDiceNumber = 1;
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  leftDiceNumber = 5;
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Right button got pressed.');
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice2.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and I tried even multiple choices that I found in Stackoverflow , but nothing it's working...

```
this.setState(() {
  leftDiceNumber = 5;
});
```

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(...));
```

insted of just setState() and didn't work

I want to change the value of `leftDiceNumber = 5` when I click on the picture
the initialised value for `leftDiceNumber` is 1

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable outside the build method.`leftDiceNumber`, else it will reset on every build.

```dart
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int leftDiceNumber = 1; //here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  leftDiceNumber = 5;
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Right button got pressed.');
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice2.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```